# Navigation Bar View As Modal View?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tab Bar based application. When the user taps a button, I'm attempting to display a view that looks as follows:

```
+----------------------------+
| |Cancel|   Title    |Done| |
+----------------------------+
|                            |
|             ...            |
+----------------------------+
```

Under IB, the code has the following hierarchy:

```
+ File's Owner
+ First Responder
+ Nav Controller
  + Nav Bar
  + View Controller
    + View
    + Nav Item
      + Bar Button
      + Bar Button
```

Making the `View` an equal node to `Nav Controller` has not helped. So I left the `View` as a child node of `Nav Controller`.

When a button is tapped, I call the following:

```
FilePicker* picker = [[FilePicker alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

For completeness, here is the declaration of the `FilePicker` (with the extra widgets removed due to trouble shooting). Adding/removing `UINavigationControllerDelegate` does not help.

```
@interface FilePicker : UIViewController
  <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
{
  UINavigationController* navController;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationController* navController;
```

Unfortunately, all I get is the blank view (the other widgets have been removed during trouble shooting). How do I force the navigation controller to be displayed? IB does not allow me to make the Navigation Controller a view connection (I can only make the View a view connection).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the gear wrong: if I use a UIViewController with a Nav Bar and Picker View, things work as expected. I should not have used a Nav Controller.

So my view is as follows:

```
+ File's Owner
+ First Responder
+ View
  + Picker
  + Nav Bar
    + Nav Item
      + Bar Button
      + Bar Button
```

Answer (score 1):

before presenting your modal view, create a navigation controller object setting the root controller to your filepicker view.  Then display the navigation controller as the modal view. (sorry for the formatting...the format buttons in the editor aren't displaying)

```
PickerView *pv = [[PickerView alloc] initWithNibName:@"PickerView" bundle:nil];
pv.ivar1 = value1;

UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pv];

[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];
[nc release];
[pv release];
```

Comment: I was using the gear wrong: if I use a UIViewController with a Nav Bar and Picker View, things work as expected. I should *not* have tried to use a Nav Controller.